# Как удалить повторяющиеся символы из строки

Tags: javascript, строки

Имеем строку: `+a1+b2*d2+a1+b3*d3`. Нужно из нее удалить все вхождения повторяющихся символов, в данном случае `+a1`. Чтобы получить `+a1+b2*d2+b3*d3`

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то:

```
var input = "+a1+b2d2+a1+b3d3";
var result = input.replace(/(\+[a-z\d]+\b)(.*?)\1/ig, '$1$2');
```

Comment: А если увеличить строку до +a1+b2d2+a1+b3d3+a3+b4d4+a3+b5d5, то уже не работает

Comment: var result = input.replace(/(\+[a-z\d]+\b)(.*?)\1/ig, '$1$2');

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = "+a1+b2d2+a1+b3d3+a3+b4d4+a3+b5d5";

var end = input.split('+').filter(function (e, i, arr) {
    return arr.lastIndexOf(e) === i;
}).join('+');

console.log(end);
```

Comment: Пример @RubaXa предпочтительней,т.к. отрабатывает быстрее.