# Регулярное выражение JavaScript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно найти все неповторяющиеся символы или по-другому - отсеять повторяющиеся символы

Пример:

> asdfasdf111133 - > asdf13

Нужна именно регулярка, без циклов и условий.

Допускается использовать максимум `match`, то есть `replace` и прочее - не подходит.
Операция должна происходить в одно действие.
Пример:

> 'asdfasdf111133'.match(/регулярка/) -> 'asdf13'

Comment: Дубль задачи, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/267610/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: @ДмитрийПриходченко Только в этом дубле нет ответа регуляркой, подходящей к данной задаче. ибо она удаляет далеко не все, из за захватывающей `(.*)`

Comment: тогда скопируйте регулярку сюда и переформулируйте вопрос имхо

Comment: `Например 'asdfasdf111133'.match(/регулярка/) -> 'asdf13'` это фантастика!

Comment: Можете обьяснить почему

Comment: Да хотя бы потому, что результатом работы match() является массив, а не строка.

Comment: Зачем такие сложные и выглядящие бредовыми условия? Я бы это вообще не регуляркой делал (если регуляркой это вообще возможно)

Answer (score 2):

Данное регулярное выражение сохраняет последнее вхождение символа:

```
var str = 'asdfasdf111133';
str.replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, ''); // "asdf13"
```

Без регулярок:

```
str = str.split('')
    .filter((x, n, s) => s.indexOf(x) == n)
    .join('');

console.log(str); // "asdf13"
```

Comment: на самом деле, не совсем то - у вас используется функция replace, которая производит  замену

Comment: @ruslik match в любом случае разбивает строку на массив, она так работает и изменить это никак нельзя. И при указанной в этом ответе регулярке она дает адекватный ответ - уникальные буквы.

Comment: еще вариант без регулярок: `[...new Set('asdfasdf111133')].join('')`

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно заметили в комментариях - без `join()`, Вам `match()` вернёт массив, а не строку, поэтому без объединения не обойтись.

В соседнем ответе (с `replace()`) выражение составлено правильно, но для использования совместно с заменой. Для `match()` же нужно использовать *negative lookahead* `(?!ABC)`, вместо *positive lookahead* `(?=ABC)`.

```js
let sTxt = 'asdfasdf111133';
let rExp = /(.)(?!.*\1)/g;

console.log(sTxt.match(rExp)); // ["a", "s", "d", "f", "1", "3"]
console.log(sTxt.match(rExp).join('')); // "asdf13"
```